# HTC Vive doesn't display with Webots

Tags: display, webots

I want to render my simulations (for example images of a Mavic2Pro camera) on a HTC Vive. When I select View > Virtual reality headset > Enable, nothing but the 3 axes within a black background displays on the headset and view window. Here's a screenshot:
[Displayed image on HTC Vive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAUdq.png)

System details:
Windows 10 OS, Webot R2020b Revision 1, GeForce GTX 1050 Ti GPU, Steam VR runtime installed.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Webots used to work with HTC Vive. However, after some update in the drivers of steam, it no longer works. This is however not in the current priorities of Cyberbotics to fix it unless some customer pays for the time spent on fixing it.